# Is the figurative "sans compter" only coupled with a verb associated with "money"?

Tags: expressions, usage

> Elle s'est **investie** sans compter dans ce projet.
>
> Elle s'est **depensée** sans compter pour la réussite de ce projet.
>
> Elle s'est **donnée** sans compter pour la réussite de ce projet.

There are a lot of verbs with the meaning of "strive", such as "s'efforcer", but I wonder if the figurative expression "sans compter" can only be coupled with a verb  that evokes the idea of "money"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sans compter* in this sense doesn't necessarily imply money, but it's usually used with a verb that implies that something gets counted, and that something is often money: *s'investir*, *se dépenser*, … Here are some examples where the semantic field of money isn't involved explicitly:

> De leurs glacières, ils sortaient de la nourriture sans compter.   ([François Lefort, *Bonjour ! Je viens mourir chez vous*, 2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=X-WH6OTeJssC&pg=PA153&dq=%22sans+compter%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sans%20compter%22&f=false))
>
> Après six années au cours desquelles je l'ai soutenu sans compter mes efforts, …   ([Jean-Yves Ollivier, *Ni vu ni connu: De Chirac et Foccart à Mandela. Ma vie de négociant en politique*, 2014](https://books.google.fr/books?id=go3HAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT114&dq=%22soutenu+sans+compter%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22soutenu%20sans%20compter%22&f=false))
>
> Emile Le Bris et Sylvie Fanchette m'ont soutenu sans compter, moralement et matériellement, …   ([Cheikh Guèye, *Touba : la capitale des mourides*, 2002](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7ufxtvMPM2YC&pg=PA5&dq=%22soutenu+sans+compter%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22soutenu%20sans%20compter%22&f=false))